# "Happy Birthday <name>" or "Happy Birthday to <name>" on a cake?

Tags: phrasing

What is better to write on a cake? "Happy Birthday `<name>`" or "Happy Birthday to `<name>`"?
Or are both of them equally fine? Or is there an alternative that's better than both?

Comment: I think most cake decorators would recommend the exclusion of the preposition, but let's wait for them to weigh in.

Comment: Seriously? "Opinion-based"?! This is what's wrong with StackExchange...

Answer (score 4):

By far, the most common phrasing is "Happy [Nth] Birthday [Name]". You can easily see this in an image search for "birthday cakes". For example:

[image: cake line 1: happy birthday, cake line 2: any name here]

(Likewise, no preposition is used for other types of cakes, such as "Congratulations [name]", "Happy Anniversary [name]".)

See also the examples here:

- [The Olde World Bakery & Cafe](http://www.theoldeworldbakery.com/birthday-cakes.html)
- [Caked de Fleur](http://www.cakesdefleur.com/birthday.php)
- [Cakeclicks](https://www.cakeclicks.com/topic/Sample+Birthday)

Comment: I've also seen some examples that include "to", e.g. [this](https://photobirthdaycake.com/images/cakes/300/make-wife-birthday-cake-with-personal-photo.png), but you may be right that the other one is more common.